# How to do remote shut down based on ping return value?

Tags: cmd

I used the following codes for bat file to remote shut down the system based on ping return value, I dont know what am i missing, it is not working please help me

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (computerlist.txt) do (
ping -n 1 %%a >NUL 2>NUL
if %errorlevel%==0 (
psexec -d \\%%a -u username -p password -s cmd /c shutdown /s
) else echo Skipping unreachable host %%a
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this to shut down the computers that are responding.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (computerlist.txt) do (
ping -n 1 %%a |find "TTL=">NUL && psexec -d \\%%a -u username -p password -s "cmd /c shutdown /s"
)
pause
```